# Older Delphi Component - B++ Builder 11 Package Install

Tags: linker, linker-errors

I'm struggling to install a few older Delphi components into C++ Builder 11.0.  This worked for me in Win10 but not working for me in Win 11.  In general, these are simple *.pas files.

Often I have to add "vcl." in front of uses definitions; i.e., vcl.Forms vs. Forms.  So with these corrections I now seem to be able to build but I have a few errors like:

ilink32:  Unable to open file VCL.CONTROLS.OBJ or Unable to open file VCL.EXTCTRLS.OBJ or Unable to open VCL.FORMS.OBJ.

It's not very clear to me how to resolve this link error.  Thoughts?

Thanks,
-Rich

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add vcl.bpi to my projects.